# Regex parse using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, regex, nokogiri

Using Nokogiri, I need to parse a block given:

```
<div class="some_class">
  12 AB / 4+ CD
  <br/>
  2,600 Dollars
  <br/> 
</div>
```

I need to get the `ab`, `cd` and `dollars` values if they exist.

```
ab = p.css(".some_class").text[....some regex....]
cd = p.css(".some_class").text[....some regex....]
dollars = p.css(".some_class").text[....some regex....]
```

Is that correct? If so, can someone help me with a regex to parse the `ab`, `cd` and `dollars` values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get a better answer you would have to clarify exactly what format the AB, CD and Dollar values take but here is a solution based on the example given. It uses a regexp grouping `()` to capture the information we're interested in. (see the bottom of the answer for more details)

```
text = p.css(".some_class").text

# one or more digits followed by a space followed by AB, capture the digits
ab = text.match(/(\d+) AB/).captures[0] # => "12"

# one of more non digits followed by a literal + followed by CD
cd = text.match(/(\d+\+) CD/).captures[0] # => "4+"

# digits or commas followed by "Dollars"
dollars = text.match(/([\d,]+) Dollars/).captures[0] # => "2,600"
```

Note that if there is no match then `String#match` returns `nil` so if the values might not exist you would need a check e.g.

```
if match = text.match(/([\d,]+) Dollars/)
  dollars = match.captures[0]
end
```

**Additional explanation of captures**

To match the amount of AB we need a pattern `/\d+ AB/` to identify the right part of the text. However, we're really only interested in the numeric part so we surround that with brackets so that we can extract it. e.g.

```
irb(main):027:0> match = text.match(/(\d+) AB/)
=> #<MatchData:0x2ca3440>           # the match method returns MatchData if there is a match, nil if not
irb(main):028:0> match.to_s         # match.to_s gives us the entire text that matched the pattern
=> "12 AB"
irb(main):029:0> match.captures     
=> ["12"]
# match.captures gives us an array of the parts of the pattern that were enclosed in ()
# in our example there is just 1 but there could be multiple
irb(main):030:0> match.captures[0]
=> "12"                             # the first capture - the bit we want
```

Take a look at the documentation for [MatchData](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/MatchData.html), in particular the [captures](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/MatchData.html#M001283) method for more details.

Comment: Note: if there is no match then it's not that your variables e.g. `dollars` will be `nil` that is the issue - it's that it would result in an attempt to call the `captures` method on `nil` which would fail, that's why you might want a check.

Comment: Ah. Ok, i understand. So what captures method is? Because now it works fine without captures to for me.

Comment: I have added some more explanation of captures to the answer. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is an older thread, but I just stumbled upon it. Here's how I'd locate the values and a usable way of storing the values:

```
require "ap"
require "nokogiri"

xml = <<EOT
<div class="some_class">
  12 AB / 4+ CD
  <br/>
  2,600 Dollars
  <br/> 
</div>
EOT

doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml)

some_class = doc.at('.some_class').text

values = some_class
  .scan(/([\d+]+) ([a-z,]+)/i)
  .each_with_object({}){ |(v,c), h| h[c] = v.to_i }

values # => {"AB"=>12, "CD"=>4, "Dollars"=>600}
```

Comment: is there a way for nokogiri to just return the data if it matches a certain regex pattern rather than returning everything and then later applying the logic to it? 
esp, when parsing a large xml file, maybe having nokogiri return just the bits we want would be faster? Or would filtering it later on would be faster? thanks.

Comment: XPath2 supports regex, whereas the older XPath1 didn't. Nokogiri's CSS supplies a few jQuery-type extensions that don't allow regex but can help. It's faster to let the libXML2 library do the lifting/searching, than to return every node to Nokogiri and then sift through them, but you could prove that to yourself using benchmarks.